# Cambiar formato de "yyyy/MM/dd" a "dd/MM/yyyy" en java

Tags: java

Amigos un gusto saludarlos, como puedo pasar de un formato a otro de fechas por ejm, en mi variable `fechaInicio` tiene este formato `2019/05/31` y lo quiero pasar a este formato `"dd/MM/yyyy"`

Tengo este simpleDate, pero no sé muy bien como acoplarlo al codigo donde se guarda en la variable `fechaInicio`:

```
SimpleDateFormat formato = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");

String fechaInicio  = obtenerFechaDesdeNombreArchivo(jsonFile.getName()).replaceAll("-", "/");
```

Espero y me puedan ayudar por favor, quedo al pendiente de sus comentario, saludos.

Comment: buenas, si es solo pasar el formato string a otro puedes: String[] array = json.getName().split("-"); y ahora String dateString = array[2] + "/" + array[1] + "/" + array[0];

Comment: SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");
Date date = format.parse(TuFecha);

Answer (score 2):

Puedes realizarlo aplicando el formato deseado mediante el método **[applyPattern("dd/MM/yyyy")](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/text/DecimalFormat.html#applyPattern-java.lang.String-)** a partir del formato inicial.

```
        //Formato inicial.  
        SimpleDateFormat formato = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy/MM/dd");
        String fechaInicio  = "2019/05/31";
        Date d = formato.parse(fechaInicio);

        //Aplica formato requerido.
        formato.applyPattern("dd/MM/yyyy");
        String nuevoFormato = formato.format(d);
```

De esta forma a partir del formato inicial `2019/05/31`, obtendrías como "nuevo formato":

```
31/05/2019
```

Comment: Muchas gracias por tu respuestas, las voy a probar :)

Answer (score 0):

Creo que con esto puedes solucionar tu problema

```
    SimpleDateFormat formatoOrigen = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy/MM/dd");
    String fechaOriginal = "2019/05/31";
    SimpleDateFormat formatoSalida = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");
    Date date = formatoOrigen.parse(fechaOriginal);
    System.out.println(formatoSalida.format(date));
```

Comment: Muchas gracias, voy a probar a ver con cual se adapta a mi problema XDD